# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException using JNDI

Tags: java, jndi

Iam trying to connect mysql by using JNDI. But it show an exception

`javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:`

See my code :

```
    VendorDataSource vds = new VendorDataSource();
    vds.setServerName("localhost");
    vds.setDatabaseName("jnditest");
    vds.setDescription("The data source for inventory and personnel");

    try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
        ctx.bind("jdbc/myds", vds);

    } catch (NamingException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/myds");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection("root", "password");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the error message :

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(Unknown Source)
    at samplemariadb.DataSourceConnectivity.main(DataSourceConnectivity.java:33)
```

Answer (score 2):

usually you need to specify where to get the InitialContext from (and where is located the jndi tree you will use)

You can do it in two ways :

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "<initialContextFactory>");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "<url>");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "<user>");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "<password>");
ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

or create a jndi.properties and place it in your classpath :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=<initialContextFactory>
java.naming.provider.url=<url>
java.naming.security.principal=<user>
java.naming.security.credentials=<password>
```

In your case it is complaining because the lack of  INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY (which depends on which Java EE server you are using).

Hope it helps

Comment: Iam trying this method also. But not able to download the fscontext.jar file from no site. Can you help me to give the proper path for downloading the fscontext.jar file?

Comment: As far as I know it was included  in the Java Web Services Developer Pack, (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-jwsdp-419428.html) but I am not sure if that's what you need.

Comment: @Haseena What do you want that for? What you want is the provider used by your container.